# Azure Traffic Manager Error: Endpoint do not has a DNS Name

Tags: asp.net, azure, dns, azure-traffic-manager

When I tried to add a mobile app as an endpoint to Azure Traffic Manager, Azure portal tells me "Failed to save configuration changes to Traffic Manager profile.  Error: The resource specified by the targetResourceId for endpoint xxxx does not have a DNS name".

But when I clone the app as a web app, and add the new web app as an endpoint to the traffic manager, everything works fine.

Can anyone tells me how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using custom domains for your mobile app? I have tried to add a mobile app to traffic manager, and it works perfectly for me. Please provide more details about how you config your mobile app so that I can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for flagging.  I've discussed  with the Web App team, and they confirm they are tracking a bug for this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll provide some details about the error to you via lync.